# NodeJS/Testacular on Jenkins CI

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm using Testacular which is a Node.js test runner for Angular/Jasmine. I can run it fine from the command line, but every time I try to run it from Jenkins build steps, it bombs out with all sorts of errors regarding environment variables. I tried the Nodejs plugin for Jenkins, but that's just to run node code snippets. Anyone know of a way to have node apps (eg. Testacular) running test under Jenkins?

Comment: Please could you add a few of the errors that your facing so we have a better idea. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to:

1. have "testacular" as a dependency in your `package.json` file.
2. install your dependencies with `npm install` (do this as a build step)
3. call it as `./node_modules/.bin/testacular start --single-run`

Assuming you have configured testacular to use PhantomJs `browsers = ['PhantomJS'];`, you just need to have the `phantomjs` binary in your path or tell testacular where it is located with an environment variable set in your shell:

```
export PHANTOMJS_BIN=$HOME/local/bin/phantomjs
```

Comment: do you run your #2 and #3 as shell script? or which option should I chose?. BTW: I'm on Windows.

Comment: #2: I use a Makefile for this.

Comment: #3: I use a Makefile for this.

Answer (score 0):

good news!

" I tried the Nodejs plugin for Jenkins, but that's just to run node code snippets. "

nope!

install the nodejs plugin see instructions here -> [NodeJS jenkins plugin broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213074/nodejs-jenkins-plugin-broken/22014948#22014948)

then tick "Provide Node/npm bin folder to PATH" and when running a "execute shell" build task, you can use nodejs, here's a example using grui

npm update
grunt
grunt --force reporting