# NodeJS jenkins plugin broken?

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have just installed the NodeJS plugin on Jenkins 1.526

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

but on the master configuration the NodeJS auto-installer does not show up, is this plugin outdated?

Comment: I am having this same issue. I have Jenkins version 2.7.2. I installed the NodeJS plugin, but it does not show up on the global configuration page. I happen to be running Jenkins from within a Docker container on a CoreOS box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works for me, but i had to restart the server for the option to appear

I see the option here: /jenkins/configure

my steps:

a) install this as normal

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin
```

b) then you go to the configure page

```
/jenkins/configure
```

c) NodeJS option should be under maven/git and ant installation options

d) Create NodeJS installiation

NodeJS- > NodeJS installations -> Add NodeJS -> Name = "NodeJS 0.11.10", tick "Install automatically", select "Install from nodejs.org", add "grunt-cli" to globally installed packages

e) Create a job and nodejs shell should be available as a build task "Execute NodeJS script"

eg do this for a simple hello world example, with echo hello world onto jenkins job output

```
var sys = require('sys');
sys.puts('NodeJS Test');
sys.puts('***************');
sys.puts('helloworld');
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable on JENKINS_HOME/configureSecurity "Cross site request forgery" attack check